# Selecting specific sql rows in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to access a database table, this table is going to have 100+ records for which I would like to pick specific rows (through their unique id). Here is some of the php code I have...

```
<?php

function connect() {
  $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'db') or die('There was a problem connecting to the db');
  return $conn;
}

function get($conn) {
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM camera") or die('There is a problem with the connection');
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($id, $camera_id, $name, $location, $camera_status, $contact_name, $contact_phone);

  $rows = array();

  while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $item = array(
             'id' => $id,
      'camera_id' => $camera_id,
           'name' => $name,
       'location' => $location,
  'camera_status' => $camera_status,
   'contact_name' => $contact_name,
  'contact_phone' => $contact_phone
);
$rows[] = $item;
  }
  return $rows;
}

$conn = connect();
$results = get($conn);

?>
```

There will be 9 results per page, these results have to be coded in manually. I am able to display all results in the database but I would like to be able to pick 9 unique results, display the contents of the row as well as offering a way to edit the entry. The unique identifier will be their $id.

What would be the easiest way to select these rows in php?

Thanks in advance!

J.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the page won't always have 9 records and they won't always be in consecutive order. Is there no way to select  for example $id = 2; in the body and display all the data for that id alone?

Comment: Please stop `foo or die()`-ing.  Killing your entire script because of a single error is bad practice at best, can be destructive to data at worst, and provides a horrible user experience *every* time.

Comment: I'm assuming I just need to spend more time and make the page load these values dynamically. I don't understand how using `limit 0,9` can help me select and display, for example, row id 13 and 45. @charles thanks for pointing out that `foo or die()`-ing is bad practice. I wish you had included some reference for rookies like myself who don't know why.

Comment: Check out [this blog post](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die) for a pretty good summary of the `foo() or die()` fiasco.  Note that this is pretty much the *only* worthwhile post on that entire site.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that post was a nice read. I've gone ahead and updated the code removing `or die()` and I think for the release version I will just make it `or trigger_error()` as per the suggestion and log those errors to a file!

Answer (score 1):

use `limit` in query for specific rows like this example

```
SELECT * FROM camera limit 0,9
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 1):

Use limits

```
$start= 0; $end=9; //you can make $start =10; $end=9; for next run and so on..
SELECT * FROM camera limit "'.$start.'","'.$end.'"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `limit` to select the lines you want after sorting by id with `order by`.
First `limit 0, 9` then on the second load use `limit 9,9`, and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

Limit should be after where clause.

Syntax :

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
[WHERE]
LIMIT number;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html

Answer (score 0):

I made the entire script load results dynamically (with `foreach` loop) instead of having to manually add them. Originally I wanted to add the rows manually because the video streams will be limited to a per client basis, so I just added an extra database column to get around this issue.

I'm still limited to 9 feeds per page so I will be using the `limit` feature for that, thanks for the help and feedback!